# How to serve an Ajax post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

This question seems simple at first glance, but has slowed down my work! Please, help me to figure out where am I making a mistake.

I would like to build a server using Ruby-on-Rails which will have one main function: to serve a post requests with some data from my client side JS. Then use jquery's Ajax method to send asynchronous requests:

```
    function processPeople() {
        SOME.api(".get", {owner_id:frnds.response[i].uid,count:"3"}, function(posts) {
                                var usefulPosts = posts.response;
                                for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'wallposts',
                data: {uid: usefulPosts[i]["from_id"], uniqpost_id: usefulPosts[i]["id"], tent:usefulPosts[i]["text"]}
            });

    };
    });
    i++;
    if (i<2) {
        setTimeout(processPeople, 1000);
    }
}
```

and here my controller where post requests are sent:

```
def create
    # debugger

    if !(Wallpost.from_user(params[:uid]).find_by_uniqpost_id(params[:uniqpost_id]))
    @newWP = Wallpost.new(:uid => params[:uid], :content => params[:content], 
            :uniqpost_id => params[:uniqpost_id])
    @newWP.save 


end
```

What if I want just to save data on server side and NOTHING more, what would I do on server side? Every time I try to post info to my sever it answers me with 500-error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template wallposts/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/yurgen/rails_project/vkraigslist/app/views"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the return of the controller. HTTP protocol requests that.

If you don't want to return any code, simply put a

```
head :ok
```

in the end of your controller.